# How to manage scatterlist for Linux crypto api use?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I need to (de)cipher some data at a time. Extra padding bytes may have to be added to the target data bytes at the beginning and at the end. The built-in crypto API works on `struct scatterlist` objects, as you can see with the definition of the encrypt method of a block cipher :

```c
int (*encrypt)(struct blkcipher_desc *desc, struct scatterlist *dst,
           struct scatterlist *src, unsigned int nbytes);
```

Now the procedure I am following for the ciphering operation :

1. Get a data buffer *buf* (length *L*)
2. Compute left padding and right padding bytes (*rpad* and *lpad*)
3. Cipher the whole thing (*lpad* and *buf* and *rpad*)
4. Get rid of the padding bytes in the result

The most simple and unefficient solution would be to allocate *L* + *rpad* + *lpad* bytes and copy the buffer's content in this new area appropriately. But since the API uses those `scatterlist` objects, I was wondering if there was a way to avoid this pure waste of resources.

I read a couple of articles on LWN about `scatterlist` chaining but a quick glance at the header file worries me : it looks like I have to *manually* set up the whole thing, which is a pretty bad practice ...

Any clue on how to use the `scatterlist` API properly ? Ideally, I would like to do the following :

1. Allocates buffers for the padding bytes for both input and output
2. Allocate a "payload" buffer that will only store the "useful" ciphered bytes
3. Create the `scatterlist` objects that includes padding buffers and target buffer
4. Cipher the whole and store the result in output padding buffers + output "payload" buffer
5. Discard the input and output padding buffers
6. Return the ciphered "payload" buffer to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having investigated through the code, I found a suitable solution. It follows quite well the procedure I listed in my question, though there are some subtle differences.

As suggested by [JohnsonDiao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2098847/johnsondiao), I dived into the **scatterwalk.c** file to see how the Crypto API was making use of the `scatterlist` objects.

The problem that has arisen is the "boundary" between two subsequent `scatterlist`. Let's say I have two chained `scatterlist`. The first one hold information about a 12 bytes buffer, the second to a 20 bytes buffer. I want to encrypt the two buffers as a whole using AES128-CTR.
In this particular case, the API will :

1. Encrypt the 12 bytes of the buffer referenced by the first `scatterlist`.
2. Increment the counter
3. Encrypt the 16 first bytes of the second scatterlist
4. Increment the counter
5. Encrypt the last remaining 4 bytes

The behaviour I would have expected was :

1. Encrypt the 12 bytes of first buffer + the 4 first bytes of second buffer
2. Increment the counter
3. Encrypt the last 16 bytes of the second buffer

Thus, to enforce this, one must allocate a 16-byte aligned padding buffer in the pattern :

> Let *n<sub>pad</sub>* the number of padding bytes needed for the requested encryption. Then we have : [image: Buf length]
>
> Where *l<sub>buf</sub>* is the total length of the padding buffer. Now, the last *l<sub>buf</sub> - n<sub>pad</sub>* bytes must be filled with the first input data bytes. If the input is too short to ensure a full copy, that's not a matter.
>
> Therefore we copy the first *l<sub>cpy</sub> = min(l<sub>buf</sub> - n<sub>pad</sub>, l<sub>data</sub>)* bytes at the offset *n<sub>pad</sub>* in the padding buffer

In short, here is the procedure :

1. Allocate the appropriate padding buffer with length *l<sub>buf</sub>*
2. Copy the first *l<sub>cpy</sub>* bytes of the payload buffer at offset *n<sub>pad</sub>* in the padding buffer
3. Reference the padding buffer in a `scatterlist`
4. Reference the payload buffer in another `scatterlist` (with a *l<sub>cpy</sub>* shift)
5. Ask for the ciphering
6. Extract the payload bytes present in the padding buffer
7. Discard the padding buffer

I tested this and it seemed to work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

first, sorry for my pour english,I am not a native english speaker.I think you are looking for 
this api in kernel " blkcipher_walk_virt" , you can find the usage of this in  ecb.c 
"crypto_ecb_crypt". and you also can see the padlock_aes.c

Comment: That is exactly what I did, unfortunately you arrived too late. Anyway, useful hint and since you cannot comment, here's a +1

Answer (score 1):

I am also learning this part. and this is my analysis:

if your encryption device need cipher 16-bytes at once, you should set the alignment to (16-1). just like the padlock_aes.c , see ecb_aes_alg.cra_alignmask. the kernel would handle
this in blkcipher_next_copy and  blkcipher_next_slow. 
but I am puzzled, in aes_generic.c the alignmask is 3, how the kernel handle this without 
blkcipher_next_copy?

Comment: It is may be the alignment required by the `scatterlist` interface. The page pointer of a `scatterlist` must be 4-aligned since the two last bits of the pointer are used to store information for `scatterlist` chaining (see http://lwn.net/Articles/234617/ ). A 3 alignmask value enforces 4-aligned pointers.